# How to set the navigator in Html that it disappears when the user decreases the width of a page?

Tags: html, navigator

How to set the horizontal navigator in Html that it disappears and is replaced by three lines button when the user decreases the width of a page?

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 

<style>


BODY {
    text-align: justify
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 85.5vw;
    background-color: gray; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0px;
    height: 2vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 black;
}
header * {
    display: inline;
}
header li {
    margin: 30px;
}
header li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    left: 10vw;
}

</style>
</head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>

<body>

<header>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">  </a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="h.html"> AAAAAAAA </a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="ht.html"> BBBBBBBBB </a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="tos.html"> CCCCCCCCCCCC </a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="cts.html"> DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD </a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="h.html"> EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE </a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="http.html"> FFFFFFFFFFFFFF </a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

</header>
<br> <br>
    <h1>H1</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

After decreasing the width of the page, the navigator bar is deformed:

[image]

I would like that navigator bar to disappear and be replaced by:

[image]

Thank you very much